# Laravel authentication custom username and password encryption

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, bcrypt

I wanted to learn Laravel, and to do so, I wanted to link my Discord bot to a monitoring website.
The user can set up a password, using a command on Discord, that is encrypted using Bcrypt (with the bcrypt npm package).
My goal is to provide a web page in which the user can enter his client ID and his previously set up password to login, then have access to some basic functionalities to manage the servers he's moderator on.

I have the following login page:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h1 class="title">Get connected !</h1>
    <h2 class="detail">Login and manage your servers !</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf

        <label for="id" class="label">Client id :</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Client id" name="id" value="{{ old('id') }}" autofocus>
        <label for="password" class="label">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">

        <input type="submit" value="{{ __('Login') }}">
    </form>
</div>

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="form-error">
        <span class="label">Your email and/or password isn't correct.</span>
    </div>
@endif
```

Also, here is my User class:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];
}
```

My *users* table has three columns:

- id (which is the client id on Discord)
- xp (integer)
- password (of Blob type, to store the bcrypt encrypted password)

Because I'm using the default authentication system, I just wrote the *username* function in **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**:

```
public function username()
{
    return "id";
}
```

That system doesn't work and I don't know why, as I've just started learning Laravel. I was thinking of an encryption issue, but Laravel seem to be using Bcrypt too.

**EDIT**
I don't have php errors, but when I try to login, I'm being told that my credentials are wrong.
I changed the password type from Blob to Varchar and the username function to a variable like:

```
protected $username = "id"
```

**EDIT 2**
My laravel version is 5.7.13.
I tried adding the table name in my User model but it still doesn't work.
About the way I'm creating my users, it's not done using php but Javascript, as you're only supposed to have the possibility to register if you're on a Discord server that has my bot in it.
When the *register* command is triggered by a user, the following function is called on my database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `addUser`(user_id VARCHAR(18), server_id VARCHAR(18)) RETURNS tinyint(1) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

IF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id=server_id) AS a) = 0) THEN 
    INSERT INTO servers VALUES (server_id);
    INSERT INTO aremembersof VALUES ("notregistered", 3, server_id);
END IF;
IF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=user_id) AS a) = 0) THEN 
    INSERT INTO users VALUES (user_id); 
END IF;

IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM aremembersof WHERE id_servers=server_id AND id=user_id) AS a) = 0) THEN 
    INSERT INTO aremembersof VALUES (user_id, 2, server_id); 
ELSE
    RETURN false;
END IF;

RETURN true;

END
```

No password is set when the user first registers. This can seem strange but the password is only used to log in the management website. To define a password, the user has to call the *setPassword* command, which code is:

```
if(args.length > 0){
    bcrypt.hash(args[0], 0, async (err, hash) => {
        await dbUtilities.execute("UPDATE users SET password = \"" + hash + "\" WHERE id = \"" + message.author.id + "\"");
        message.reply({embed: {
            color: parseInt(colors.success, 16),
            description: "Your password has been changed!"
        }});
    });

    return;
}

message.reply({embed: {
    color: parseInt(colors.danger, 16),
    description: "You have to specify a password!"
}});
```

Actually some other checks are done in order to verify the user is not setting his new password from a public channel but it's not relevant here.
Also, *args[0]* corresponds to the password typed by the user.

**EDIT 3**

As suggested, I changed my system so that the password has to be set on the website directly. Thus, the setPassword command sets a token that is used on the website on an activation page.
Here is the function called when submitting the form:

```
public function activatePost(Request $request)
{
    \Debugbar::info($request);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'token' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'
    ]);

    $password_reset = PasswordReset::where('token', $request->token)->first();

    if($password_reset != null)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $password_reset->id)->first();
        $user->password = \Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('login')->with('message', 'Your password has been set!');
    }
    else {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

I still can't connect.

Comment: You've done an awesome job of laying out your code, but you'll get quicker answers if you refine your question, what kinds of errors are you getting? Do you have the php logs we can look at? [have you read this?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I'm worried your question could be seen as too broad & get flags and downvotes. Rather than show us all the code, find the error, that'll shed more light on the situation.

Comment: in your `LoginController` try `protected $username = 'id';`

Comment: The password should be a varchar, not a blob.

Comment: I added a few details, but I don't know where the problem is, so I'm afraid I can't give you more

Comment: @christophechichmanian which Laravel version are you using? Also how are you creating your user? The code you use to create your user would be helpful in determining the issue. Your user model doesn't have a database table defined, typically `protected $table = 'users';`.

Comment: @adam I edited my post to add the things you asked for

Comment: It looks like you want to login via Discord, if that is the case just bypass local authentication. So if you successfully authenticate at Discord, then you successfully authenticate within Laravel. Essentially Discord becomes your Identity Provider. If you still wish to authenticate with Laravel you’ll need a unique identifier and a password.

Comment: You mean I should be using some sort of Discord API that allows me to connect with the Discord account? If that's what you meant, it could be interesting but I'd rather start with a classic authentication using Laravel.

Comment: @christophechichmanian Exactly. If you want to use Laravel, you're going to need an identifier and password prior to attempting authentication.

Comment: @adam I already have those: the discord client id (unique identifier for each discord user) and the password defined by the user himself using the setPassword command. Those corresponds to the fields called "id" and "password" (I think I forgot to mention the "id" field on my database wasn't an autoincrement field but the one that holds the client id)

Comment: @christophechichmanian, are these being saved into your users table(laravel) prior to attempting authentication with laravel?

Comment: @adam yes they are

Comment: @christophechichmanian is there any way to set the password using laravel instead of `bcrypt.hash(...`

Comment: @adam I could build an other system that would let the user set his password from the website yeah, but why are you asking ?

Comment: From the code you posted everything looks correct, so my guess is the computed hash is what might be causing the authentication failure.

Comment: @adam Oh okay, I'll try my new system and then tell you if it works (I'm thinking of a command that generates an unique token that is used on a webpage to set the password)

Comment: @adam I edited my post, this new system doesn't work (the password is set but I still can't login). I posted the function called when the form is submitted.

Comment: Try creating a user directly with the website too. Are you sure `$password_reset->id` matches up with your user id?

Comment: @adam Yes I am, indeed I saw the password change on my database. Also, I don't want the user to register directly on the website, do I still have to try?

Comment: @adam I found the solution! You were right about the fact that the password should be set on the website directly, but it didn't work because of the `protected $username = 'id'`. I tried again with the username funciton (and not the attribute) and it works!

Comment: Ah. Good wasn’t sure which Laravel version you were on. I believe the username method was added in later versions of 5.*.